# Input crash (C++)

Tags: c++, input, crash

Hello i've written a code, but if i want to run the code after i've inputted the code it just crashes. 
The program should pick the first 10 out of a vector, pick the highest one and destroy everything before that and refill it until it's ten long again. 
I've used a for loop to do this. I've just started with this like 2 months.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int Aantal;
cin >> Aantal;
vector<int> F(Aantal);
for(int i=0; i<Aantal; i++)
{
cin >> F[i];
    if(Aantal>1000)
    {
        cerr << "You're above 1000" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(Aantal<20)
    {
        cerr << "You're below 20" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(i>Aantal)
        {
            cerr << "Not above 'Aantal'" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    if(i<0)
        {
            cerr << "Not smaller than 0!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
}
for(int z=0; z<Aantal; z++)
{
if(z == 0){
    int a = 0;
}
int a;
vector<int> arr(F.begin()+a, F.begin()+10+a);
int c = *max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
cout << c << endl;
vector<int>::iterator q;
q = find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), c);
int pos = distance(arr.begin(), q);
arr.erase(arr.begin(),arr.begin()+pos);
int a1 = 10-arr.size();
int b = a+a1;
a = b;
if(a+10>Aantal)
    {
    break;
    }
arr.erase(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

Comment: Can you explain what are trying to do here? `for(int z=0; z<Aantal; z++)
{
if(z == 0){
    int a = 0;
}
int a;
vector<int> arr(F.begin()+a, F.begin()+10+a);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
int a;
vector<int> arr(F.begin()+a, F.begin()+10+a);
```

You create a variable `a`, never initialize it and then you use it to construct the vector.  Since `a` has a garbage value this is going to mess up the vector creation as more than likely you will be getting the wrong positions.

I am not sure what you are doing right before that with:

```
for(int z=0; z<Aantal; z++)
{
if(z == 0){
    int a = 0;
}
```

As all this does is set `a` to zero and then you discard `a` as it was declared in the if block.

Comment: I want to keep a going with counting how should i do that? i need a solution for deleting and refilling of the vector.